# Spring : how to map Page<Entity> to Page<Object>

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a Repositoy (StockRepository ) class which extends from JpaRepository.
When calling the method  findAll(Pageable pageable);  the return result is  `Page<Stock>`.

Now I want to convert the  `Page<Stock>` to  `Page<StockDto>`. But the compiler give the error below.
How can I correct this Compile error ?

```
import org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter;
...
    public Page<StockDto> getAllStocksPageable(int pageNumber, int pageSize) {
    
        Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(pageNumber, pageSize);
        Page<Stock> stocks = stockRepository.findAll(pageable);
    
        Page<StockDto> dtoPage = stocks.map(new Converter<Stock, StockDto>() {
            @Override
            public StockDto convert(Stock entity) {
                StockDto stockDto = new StockDto();
                ...
                return stockDto;
            }
    
        });
    
        return null;
    
    }
```

[image]

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "stock")
public class Stock {
        ....
}


// Pojo
public class StockDto {
    ....
 }


@Repository
public interface StockRepository extends JpaRepository<Stock, Integer> {
    ....
}
```

Comment: Can you show the service code where you map from entity to your DTO?

Comment: I've added the service code

Comment: It would help future searchers if you copied and pasted the error stack trace, rather than inserting a screenshot.

Comment: Seriously @user2023141, it would help if you copied and pasted the stack trace instead of giving an image. While similar questions have been asked before, most of the questions are people who didn't realise that you had to pass the parameters at all (!) or are questions about the complexities of generics. I'm astonished to find that noone's asked a question about what this error message means (which is that you're passing the wrong type).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is pretty clear: `Page.map()` accepts a `Function`, but you've given it a `Converter`. Replace `new Converter(` with `new Function(` and `convert(` with `apply(` and it'll compile:

```java
Page<StockDto> dtoPage = stocks.map(new Function<Stock, StockDto>() {
    @Override
    public StockDto apply(Stock entity) {
        StockDto stockDto = new StockDto();
        ...
        return stockDto;
    }
});
```

Better yet, use a lambda:

```java
Page<StockDto> dtoPage = stocks.map(entity -> {
        StockDto stockDto = new StockDto();
        ...
        return stockDto;
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I would like to suggest a slightly different approach, create a data projection and let the Repository just return a page of the DTO for you.
Here's an example assuming that your DTO contains a `name` and `id` field.

```
public interface StockDTOView {
   public getName();
   public getId();
}
```

The repository method would be written like this:

```
Page<StockDTOView> findAllProjectedBy(Pageable pageable);
```

When you call this method on your repository, you'll get back a page of the projection, there's no need to do any conversions.

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using a Converter coming from Spring (does not implement Function).
If you use the one in guava 27.0, the Converter abstract class (implements Function interface) has 2 abstract methods to implement:

```
import com.google.common.base.Converter;
//...

    Page<StockDto> dtoPage = stocks.map(new Converter<Stock, StockDto>() {
        @Override
        protected StockDto doForward(final Stock stock) {
            StockDto stockDto = new StockDto();
            // ...
            return stockDto;
        }

        @Override
        protected Stock doBackward(final StockDto dto) {
            // probably you don't need this, can just return a null,
            return null;
        }
    });
```

Comment: TIL about Guava Converter, thanks! In this case, though, OP might as well just provide a `Function`.